# Do Spellblade abilities scale off of Attack or Magic (or both)?

Tags: final-fantasy-record-keeper

Cloud is a pretty awesome dude. He can use **Spellblade** abilities like Fire Strike and Drain Strike and do lots of damage and target enemy elemental weaknesses! It's great!

But I find myself dithering about how to equip Cloud. Specifically, I have some really nice armor pieces that boost Magic, as well as Defense and Attack. And I have some other really nice armor pieces that don't boost Magic, but boost Defense and Attack by slightly more!

If I give Cloud the gear that boosts his Magic stat, will his Spellblade abilities do more damage? Or is it purely based on his ATK from his weapon and other gear?

Comment: The comments on this [this](https://ffrkstrategy.gamematome.jp/game/951/wiki/Ability_Other_Spellblade) strategy page seem to indicate that Attack is the primary driver for Spellblade damage, although magic does affect it as a secondary stat. Some people seem to be testing it, but their details are still vague and I can't find a more authoritative source.